# How can validate multidates in element with regexp PHP Zend Framework

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

I have field input with multidatepicker select, multidatepicker enter dates  in field like: `2016-10-02`, `2016-10-13`, `2016-10-25`.
How can validate all dates or one, maybe I can with array regexp validator if exist?

```
$element_edit->addValidator ('regex', false, array(
    'pattern'=>'/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/',//for only one
    'messages'=>array(
        'regexNotMatch'=>'Validate error')
    )
);
$form->addElement($element_edit);
```

Comment: What kind of patterns are you looking for? Comma-delimited dates? I guess you are looking for `'pattern'=>'/^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})(?:,\s*(?1))*$/'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a way to validate a chunk of comma-separated (with or without whitespace in-between) dates in a specific format.

You may use

```
'pattern'=>'/^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})(?:,\s*(?1))*$/'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WGnVh8/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})` - your single date string pattern: 4 digits, `-`, 2 digits, `-` and 2 digits
- `(?:,\s*(?1))*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `,` - comma
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `(?1)`  - the same pattern as in Group 1 (your specific date pattern)
- `$` - end of string (may be replaced with `\z` to disallow newline symbol at the end)

Answer (score 0):

That's easy enough. We use Zend at work, so I deal with it a lot.

```
$this->addElement('text', 'firstname', array(
       'label'      => 'Your first name:',
       'required'   => true,
       'validators' => array(
         array('regex', false, array(
      'pattern'   => '{The pattern}',
      'messages'  =>  'Your firvalidation message'))
    )
));
```

Comment: You example work for only one date me need validate multi dates, that meen me need someone like patterns array for one element.